# Gigabyte radeon rx580 gaming 4GB, low mhs problem (17mhs stock / 22mhs bios mod)

Tags: mining

I have big problem with my Gigabyte radeon rx580 gaming 4GB when I getting on stock settings only 17mhs and when I try all settings, drivers… same like on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCSuON1fvZ0 I got only 22mhs, I am running on windows 7, can it have different with windows 10 ?
My hardware is
Motherboard - Asus prime H270-PLUS
RAM - DDR4 4gb 2 400 MHz
GPU - Gigabyte radeon rx580 gaming 4GB

Answer (score 1):

Not a true answer but more confirmation, I also have the aorus rx580 and get 18mh/s using claymore on windows 7. Also the aorus engine just crashes the whole computer on launch. Fixed that by renaming mbled. Exe and the gvledservice.Exe. So as a fix for the fan, I had to use msi  afterburner. These cards are definitely a scenario where you get what you pay for. Just wish there were other models in stock!